# How to calculate portfolio returns out of a large dataframe with the portfolio stock tickers in a list? (in python)

Tags: python, stock, portfolio

I have a python DataFrame with 503 stocks with the index being 6 month periods. I wrote an algorithm to select stocks per period and the output of this algorithm is a list containing 10 stocks (listed as the stock tickers) per period.

I already have a dataframe with the returns per period per stock (all 503), but i want to create a new dataframe containing only the returns of the selected stocks per period, all other stocks should have a value of 0 as they are not in the portfolio in a given period.

I have tried multiple ways of coding this but all lead to a dataframe with every value being 0, or a dataframe with over 300 rows (the initial amount of rows/periods was 19). I thought it might just be duplicates but even with after removing any duplicates there where still rows that had the same index but different values. I just do not seem to understand how to solve this problem.

Additional info,
stocklist: list containing 10 stock tickers of the chosen stocks inside the portfolio
six_monthly_returns: containing 503 stock with as values the 6 monthly return of those stocks, each row is a 6 month period with the index being the ending date of that period

The code below was my last attempt, this code amounted to 300+ values

```
portfolio_returns = []

for stock in stocklist:
    selected_data = six_monthly_returns.loc[six_monthly_returns.index, stock]
    portfolio_returns.append(selected_data)

selected_returns_df = pd.concat(portfolio_returns, axis=0)
selected_returns_df = selected_returns_df.fillna(0)
```

this code lead to a dataframe with the same format as my six_monthly_returns dataframe, but with every value being 0:

```
for date in six_monthly_returns.index:
    for stock in six_monthly_returns.columns:
        if stock in stocklist:
            six_monthly_returns.at[date, stock] = six_monthly_returns.at[date, stock]
        else:
            six_monthly_returns.at[date, stock] = 0
```

Comment: Your question needs a minimal reproducible example consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and only the relevant code necessary to reproduce the problem. See [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) for best practices related to Pandas questions